# DatacontractSerializer in Java

Tags: java, .net, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer

Is there a method or library in Java which can deserialize a .net object which was serialized by DataContractSerializer?

My Situation:

I want to create a java-client which can communicate with Microsoft MQ (MSMQ) over http.
I want to use the DataContractSerializer in .Net and an Serializer in Java so that .Net can read the content of the message which is serialized by java.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the jackson json serializer. Additionally i use the Bson4jackson library to serialize byte arrays. This is a fast solution for me.

On the .net side i use the NewtonSoft Json serializer (deserializes too) with BsonWriter/Reader to receive and send messages.